# Throwing inside a catch block in a nested Promise to trigger the catch block of outer Promise, is there an alternative cleaner way?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I'm nesting Promises and I have to know whether the nested Promise is a rejected Promise or a fulfilled Promise to know whether to trigger the outer Promise chain's catch. To differentiate if the nested Promise is rejected or fulfilled, I use a `throw` in my nested Promise's `catch` to indicate rejection; while fulfillment is always indicated when there's no `throw` in my nested Promise's `catch`. Please take a look at the example below:

```js
let test = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(42);
}).then((e) => {
  console.log(e);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { //Error happens inside this nested Promise
    resolve(32);
  }).then((e) => {
    console.log(e);
    //Run other processes that may lead to an error
  }).catch((e) => { //I added this catch block for error detection, whatever error it might be
    console.log(e);
    throw(e); //I'm throwing (e) from the inner Promise's catch so that the returned Promise in the outer then is a rejected Promise, which will be "caught" by the catch block of the outer Promise
  });
}).catch((e) => {
  console.log(e); //I handle error that happen may either in the inner Promise or the outer Promise here
});
```

The above shows what I meant by `throw`-ing inside the `catch` block of my nested Promise. Is the above the standard way to indicate that a nested Promise failed, or is there an alternative cleaner method to achieve what I want? As you can see, I'm practically `throw`-ing twice inside my nested Promise to indicate rejection. Is there a way where I can `throw` once and indicate Promise rejection?

**EDIT**

The reasons I'm using a `catch` block in my inner Promise **and** my outer Promise: I want to detect error inside my inner Promise, and said detection is done using my inner `catch` block; I want to handle the error that may happen in the inner Promise or in the outer Promise with the same handler, and that is done using my outer `catch` block. Because `catch`-ing inside my inner Promise `return`s a Promise that is considered fulfilled to my outer Promise's `then` block, I decided to use `throw` inside my inner `catch` block to indicate that it actually **isn't fulfilled** if it reached the inner `catch` block. I've also edited my code to indicate that the error happening inside my inner Promise is **not manually triggered** by me `throw`-ing in the code.

Comment: Why do you use catch/throw block inside nested promise? It's redundant. Use catch if you don't want your inner promise to be rejected or let your top-level promise do the job

Comment: @AndreiBelokopytov Not always, but it's a good design to handle error in one place at any level. It depends on the scenario. Imagine that you'd like to log the error, change some state for that specific error - it's better to have it in one place (imagine the nested Promise consumed as a function from other module).

Comment: @tomericco Thank you. Then in your opinion, is *handling error in one place at any level* and indicating a nested Promise's rejection by using a `throw` inside my inner Promise `catch`'s block a good practice?

Comment: @tomericco I agree with you about error handling but your example does the opposite thing. You handled error in the inner promise, why do you need to throw it? If you want to handle error in the outer code then you don't need a catch block inside the inner promise.

Comment: @RichardW See my answer below. Basically it depends of the scenario. If there's meaning to distinguish between the layers, it's a good practice (for example, the nested is reading from DB and the outer is processing data - you'd like to know about each of these steps errors separately), otherwise it's redundant. But as I said in my answer, it's better to call the `reject` function. Anyway I'd use `async/await`

Comment: @tomericco I see, thank you. I think that I need to learn about `async/await` as it seems like my questions seem to always be responded with '`async/await` is more readable' or something along that line. Thank you once again.

Comment: Instead of using throw('error') you should use return Promise.reject(new Error('error')). If you use Promises you should use the Promise functions because they're made exactly for Promises and have no unexpected interactions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the clean way to do this would be using async/await. But before going there, is your question how to not run the outer promise when the inner promise fails?

**The example below:**

- When the inner promise rejects, the chain stops.
- When the outer promise rejects, the inner is already fulfilled.

```js
const fun42 = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() =>{
            resolve(42)
            reject('something at fun 42 went wrong')
        }, 500)
    })
}

const fun32 = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() =>{
            //resolve(32)
            reject('something at fun 32 went wrong')
        }, 500)
    })
}

fun32().then(x => {
    console.log(x)
    return fun42()
}).then( y => {
    console.log(y)
}).catch (e => {
    console.log(e)
})
```

Comment: To your question: yes, I do not want to run the `then`s in the outer Promise when inner Promise is rejected, therefore only going immediately to the `catch` block. However, from the comment I've read and from the example you've given, seems like I made a mistake in adding a `catch` block in my inner Promise.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's a question of design. Error handling should happen in one place on each level (like you did in your example). The nested catch function handles the error the decide whether it should propagate it or quietly finish it (like your wrote).

In that specific example I would use the `reject` function of the wrapping Promise to reject it, other than throwing an error.

Comment: I think that I missed a point: how do I detect an error happening inside my inner Promise without using `catch`? The reason I used `catch` was to know that something erroneous happened inside my inner Promise. Note that my example above always ends with `throw`. In the real code I'm working on, the Promise can either be fulfilled or rejected. And to detect said rejection because of an error, I used a `catch` to detect said error and a `throw` to "tell" the outer Promise that something erroneous happened inside my inner Promise to skip the next `then`s of my outer Promise.

Comment: I dont agree, that always error handling should happen once per level. It is a great benefit that .catch returns a Promise so you can add a .catch for every .then in a Promise chain and can handle each .then's errors by it own .catch instead of handling all errors of all .thens in a chain at only one point.

Comment: @RichardW: If you want to catch an error without the use of catch you have to know what type of error you expect. Let say you would do (a / b), then b cannot be zero. Add to your code `if (b === 0) return console.log('cannot divide by zero')`. That would end the chain as well.

Comment: @Edwin There are all different types of error that may happen and I don't want to specify each one of them (because there are a lot), thus the use of `catch`. I presume that detecting error without knowing which type of error that happens and not using `catch` is impossible, then? For reference, here is the list of errors I'm talking about: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors

Comment: The error listed in the reference will bubble up to the catch at the end of the chain. If the error occurs at step n in the chain. All steps after n will not be taken, the catch will return. All steps before n are resolved.

Comment: @Edwin I see! Even steps (`then`s, in my case) after n that are located on different level of Promise chains (in my case, the outer Promise's `then`s are automatically ignored when an error happens in my inner Firebase Promise-returning methods) are not taken?